# How to remove duplicate entries in array but keep their values by overwriting

Tags: php, arrays

I have the below array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [contact_id] => 1 // *
            [exact_email_found] => 0
            [half_email_found] => 0
            [possible_by_postal_code] => 1
            [found_first_name] => 0
            [found_last_name] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [contact_id] => 3
            [exact_email_found] => 0
            [half_email_found] => 0
            [possible_by_postal_code] => 0
            [found_first_name] => 1
            [found_last_name] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [contact_id] => 2 // **
            [exact_email_found] => 0
            [half_email_found] => 0
            [possible_by_postal_code] => 0
            [found_first_name] => 1
            [found_last_name] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [contact_id] => 1 // *
            [exact_email_found] => 0
            [half_email_found] => 0
            [possible_by_postal_code] => 0
            [found_first_name] => 0
            [found_last_name] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [contact_id] => 2 // **
            [exact_email_found] => 1
            [half_email_found] => 0
            [possible_by_postal_code] => 0
            [found_first_name] => 0
            [found_last_name] => 0
        )

)
```

I am trying to make that array "be merged but keep the overwritten values".

Let me explain further. If you look at array[0] you can see `[possible_by_postal_code] => 1`. This, has a `[contact_id] => 1`. If you look below you can see array[3] has the same id but `[possible_by_postal_code] => 0` and `[found_last_name] => 1` instead.

In the new array i am trying to accomplish the below :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [contact_id] => 1 // *
            [exact_email_found] => 0
            [half_email_found] => 0
            [possible_by_postal_code] => 1
            [found_first_name] => 0
            [found_last_name] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [contact_id] => 3
            [exact_email_found] => 0
            [half_email_found] => 0
            [possible_by_postal_code] => 0
            [found_first_name] => 1
            [found_last_name] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [contact_id] => 2 // **
            [exact_email_found] => 1
            [half_email_found] => 0
            [possible_by_postal_code] => 0
            [found_first_name] => 1
            [found_last_name] => 0
        )   

)
```

Array[0] which has `contact_id = 1` exists only one time now and values `possible_by_postal_code` and `found_last_name` have `1` as value.

Notice 1 : This is just an example, my array has more than `200` objects plus it is randomized. That means a `contact_id = 5` could be at position `0` and `189`.

Notice 2 : Duplicate entries may be more than just `2`.

> Main .php file

```
$mTempDBUsers = getDataOfTempDB();

foreach($mTempDBUsers as $index => $mCurrentUser){


    $allUserData = [];
    $allUserConfig = [];

    $mCurrentUserEmail = $mCurrentUser['email'];
    $mCurrentPostalCode = $mCurrentUser['postal_code'];
    $mCurrentLastName   = $mCurrentUser['lastname'];
    $mCurrentFirstName  = $mCurrentUser['firstname'];

    if($mCurrentPostalCode == "EX23 8JS") {

        $current_user_config = array(
            "exact_email_found" => 0,
            "half_email_found" => 0,
            "possible_by_postal_code" => 0,
            "found_first_name" => 0,
            "found_last_name" => 0,
        );


        if (tryToFindUserWithEmail($mCurrentUserEmail, "")) {

            $current_user_config['exact_email_found'] = 1;

            $tempArray = tryToFindUserWithEmail($mCurrentUserEmail, $current_user_config);

            $allUserData = array_merge($allUserData, $tempArray);

        }

        if (tryToFindUserWithEmailHalf($mCurrentUserEmail, "")) {

            $current_user_config = array(
                "exact_email_found" => 0,
                "half_email_found" => 0,
                "possible_by_postal_code" => 0,
                "found_first_name" => 0,
                "found_last_name" => 0,
            );

            $current_user_config['half_email_found'] = 1;


            $tempArray = tryToFindUserWithEmailHalf($mCurrentUserEmail, $current_user_config);

            $allUserData = array_merge($allUserData, $tempArray);

        }


        if (tryToFindUserBy("mailing_postal_code", $mCurrentPostalCode, "")) {


            $current_user_config = array(
                "exact_email_found" => 0,
                "half_email_found" => 0,
                "possible_by_postal_code" => 0,
                "found_first_name" => 0,
                "found_last_name" => 0,
            );

            $current_user_config['possible_by_postal_code'] = 1;

            $tempArray = tryToFindUserBy("mailing_postal_code", $mCurrentPostalCode, $current_user_config);

            $allUserData = array_merge($allUserData, $tempArray);


        }

        if (tryToFindUserBy("lastname", str_replace(' ', '', $mCurrentLastName), "")) {

            $current_user_config = array(
                "exact_email_found" => 0,
                "half_email_found" => 0,
                "possible_by_postal_code" => 0,
                "found_first_name" => 0,
                "found_last_name" => 0,
            );

            $current_user_config['found_last_name'] = 1;

            $tempArray = tryToFindUserBy("lastname", str_replace(' ', '', $mCurrentLastName), $current_user_config);

            $allUserData = array_merge($allUserData, $tempArray);

        }

        if(tryToFindUserBy("firstname", $mCurrentFirstName, "")) {


            $current_user_config = array(
                "exact_email_found" => 0,
                "half_email_found" => 0,
                "possible_by_postal_code" => 0,
                "found_first_name" => 0,
                "found_last_name" => 0,
            );


            $current_user_config['found_first_name'] = 1;

            $tempArray = tryToFindUserBy("firstname", $mCurrentFirstName, $current_user_config);

            $allUserData = array_merge($allUserData, $tempArray);

        }

        print_r($allUserData);



    }

}
```

> Function : tryToFindUserBy

```
function tryToFindUserBy($mTypeOfSearch, $mInfoOfCurrentUser, $current_user_config){

    global $connection;

    $usersArray = [];

    $query_select = "SELECT * FROM main_db WHERE upper($mTypeOfSearch) = upper('$mInfoOfCurrentUser')";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query_select);

    $num_rows = $result->num_rows;

    if($num_rows >= 1){
        for($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++) {
            $usersArray[$i] = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            if($current_user_config != "") {
                foreach ($current_user_config as $index => $config) {
                    $usersArray[$i][$index] = $config;
                }
            }
        }

        return $usersArray;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

> Function : tryToFindUserWithEmail

```
function tryToFindUserWithEmail($mEmail, $current_user_config){

    global $connection;

    $usersArray = [];

    $query_select = "SELECT * FROM main_db WHERE upper(email) = upper('$mEmail')";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query_select);

    $num_rows = $result->num_rows;

    if($num_rows >= 1){
        for($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++) {
            $usersArray[$i] = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            if($current_user_config != "") {
                foreach ($current_user_config as $index => $config) {
                    $usersArray[$i][$index] = $config;
                }
            }
        }

        return $usersArray;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

> Function : tryToFindUserWithEmailHalf

```
function tryToFindUserWithEmailHalf($mEmail, $current_user_config){

    global $connection;

    $usersArray = [];

    $mEmail = explode("@", $mEmail)[0];

    $query_select = "SELECT * FROM main_db WHERE upper(email) LIKE upper('$mEmail%')";


    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query_select);

    $num_rows = $result->num_rows;

    if($num_rows >= 1){
        for($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++) {
            $usersArray[$i] = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            if($current_user_config != "") {
                foreach ($current_user_config as $index => $config) {
                    $usersArray[$i][$index] = $config;
                }
            }
        }

        return $usersArray;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

> Function getDataOfTempDB

```
function getDataOfTempDB(){

    global $connection;

    $usersArray = [];

    $query_select = "SELECT * FROM temp_db";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query_select);

    $num_rows = $result->num_rows;


    for($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++) {
        $usersArray[] = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }


    mysqli_free_result($result);

    return $usersArray;

}
```

Comment: show your current code

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php this function

Comment: The solution is called a `FLOC` and stands for `A Few Lines of Code` which of course **you have to write** What you have provided is a **Specification** We **do not write code for you** from specifications

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Code added, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Code added, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Didn't share code because it would be kind of chaotic, feel free to ask me if there is something not understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $newArray = [];
    foreach ($myArray as $key => $row) {
        if (isset($newArray[$row['contact_id']])) {
            foreach ($row as $k => $r) {
                if($r ){
                    $newArray[$row['contact_id']][$k] = $r;
                }
            }
        } else{
            $newArray[$row['contact_id']] = $row;
        }
    }
```

the result will be something like this:

```
    array (size=3)
      1 => 
        array (size=6)
          'contact_id' => int 1
          'exact_email_found' => int 0
          'half_email_found' => int 0
          'possible_by_postal_code' => int 1
          'found_first_name' => int 0
          'found_last_name' => int 1
      3 => 
        array (size=6)
          'contact_id' => int 3
          'exact_email_found' => int 0
          'half_email_found' => int 0
          'possible_by_postal_code' => int 0
          'found_first_name' => int 1
          'found_last_name' => int 0
      2 => 
        array (size=6)
          'contact_id' => int 2
          'exact_email_found' => int 1
          'half_email_found' => int 0
          'possible_by_postal_code' => int 0
          'found_first_name' => int 1
          'found_last_name' => int 0
```

Comment: You are a God. Thank you.